# Azure CDN edge nodes and dynamic content from origin server

Tags: caching, azure, cdn, etag, azure-cdn

I have a predominantly static site with one specific dynamic page that I have placed a cache header of max-age=7200 and an ETag equal to a new GUID every time the origin server is hit with a new request.

I was examining the response of this .aspx page via Fiddler and noticed that the first few times I accessed it via CDN the ETag kept changing (meaning the origin server was being hit the 3-4 times despite the 7200 max-age).  Then I reached a point where I would refresh over the course of 2 hours (7200 seconds) and the max-age was respected and the ETag remained the same.

After this 2 hours passed, I noticed a new response with young cache age and new ETag (let's say it was "12345678".  However, a subsequent request again ignored my max-age and pulled a newer copy from origin with a new ETag.  I made a couple more requests only to see new ETags each time.

THEN, I hit refresh again and lo and behold I was displayed the same response and ETag "12345678" from several requests ago.

Is this happening because different edge nodes are being called and they are independently getting populated from origin upon cache expiration?  Is it the case that sometimes I may be getting content from a different edge node hence I get a different ETag, but then there are times that I get locked into a specific edge node that respects the max-age for the full 7200 seconds?